# adding coordinates to google map on android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have parsed some XML data from a URL to display in a list view on an Android device. It works as expected due to some research and help from people on this site.

what I want to do is now take these coordinates and add a map to my project and create an on-click event listener function so that when I click on a particular set of data it can be displayed on the map...I am not sure how to move forward with this.i eventually want to have the option of selecting one at a time to view on the map and also a larger map view with all coordinates

I will post my current result and the code that I have that gets the XML data for me..any help would be much appreciated.[current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W2xV.png)

part of the Item Class

```
  public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(Double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (new StringBuilder()).append("title: \n").append(title).append("\n")
                .append("link: ").append(link).append("\n")
                .append("geo-lat: ").append(lat).append("\n")
                .append("geo-lon: ").append(lon).toString();
    }
}
```

part of the main activity class

```
   } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("geo:lat")) {
                    if (insideItem) {
                        //extract the text between <geo:lat> and </geo:lat>
                        item.setLat(Double.valueOf(xpp.nextText()));
                    }
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("geo:long")) {
                    if (insideItem) {
                        //extract the text between <geo:lat> and </geo:lat>
                        item.setLon(Double.valueOf(xpp.nextText()));
                    }
                }
            }
```

I just don't know how to use these returned values to populate a map in my android project

Comment: Do you want to show a maps image with those coordinates and open Google Maps on its click?

Comment: yeah..either that or add a map view to the project which can show the data....as I said I'm not sure where to go from here....so any help however small would be amazing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to generate a Google Maps API key.

Place an ImageView and load this URL into that ImageView:

https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=latitude,longitude&zoom=15&size=1280x720&sensor=false&markers=latitude,longitude&key=YOUR_API_KEY

And on your button's `OnClickListener()`:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f?q=%f,%f",
                    latitude,
                    longitude,
                    latitude,
                    longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

This will open Google Maps app to those coordinates.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response so just to verify....I add an image view to my activity.main file...load the url into the image view...then create a new button adding the code provided to the o'clock listener....sorry i'm a bit stumped I know some java but i'm new to Android just been a couple of weeks

Comment: Yes. Add an ImageView to your activity and load that URL in that ImageView. And set OnClickListener on that ImageView to open Google Maps.

Comment: Hi...okay so its not working but its only because of my lack of experience I know that your solution is correct....is there any way that you could show me how to implement these changes...again I do appreciate the help